# Rsync in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) - prevent permission denied for windows files

Tags: rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to run rsync from within WSL and backup my windows copy. (Because the windows tool does not work. If you use it, check your backups! Anyway, so...) I am mounting my backup drive with `sudo mount -t drvfs P: /mnt/p` and then I use rsync to backup `/mnt/c/Users/username/`. Though certain directories are read protected and I get `permission denied`. Is there a way to give rsync (or WSL) the rights to read those files and directories on the windows system?

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME='Automated-Backup'
LOGSTDERR=/tmp/${NAME}.err
LOGSTDOUT=/tmp/${NAME}.log

sudo mount -t drvfs V: /mnt/v
sudo mount -t drvfs B: /mnt/b

source='/mnt/v/'
target='/mnt/b/Backup'

sudo rsync --delete \
      --exclude='*Trash*' \
      --exclude='$RECYCLE.BIN' \
      --exclude='System Volume Information' \
      -aAXzv \
      --progress \
      $source \
      $target 2>${LOGSTDERR} | tee $LOGSTDLOG

cat $LOGSTDERR
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: Right to downvote should be reserved to responsible users.

Comment: I noticed that rsync was copying read-only files over as read-only, and then those files become non-updateable.  This was happening to me with some git repo files.  Windows "file properties" showed the files as fully writeable, but in WSL (v1) if I used "ls -l" I could see that the files had permissions like "-r--r--r--" so it made sense that rsync trying to update them got "permission denied".  To possibly fix this, I have updated the permissions on the remote side to be writeable and I am using rsync with the "--no-perms" flag so that hopefully it will not create more read-only files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion, but it is currently untested.

WSL runs with the same permissions as any other app, so to get full OS filesystem permissions, you'll need to run it as an admin. Find the exe or app for WSL that you use (or open a cmd prompt as admin) and try running bash from there.

Note that there may be good reasons for preventing those accesses, like those files being in use — so I'd also suggest creating a different user and running it from there.

Comment: Also `sudo rsync` seems to fix it!

Comment: But it is not a great solution.